# Applying types to DataColumns after parsing from CSV

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, .net, datatable

I'm reading in a CSV file that is modeled after a table from a SQL database and is put into a datatable. But right now all values are just added in as a string. Any recommendations as to how to convert all the columns to their appropriate types such as all TRUE/FALSE values to boolean and numeric values to int/double? The columns SHOULDNT change so I suppose I could just say "if the header is 'PropertyID' the column is type Int" etc but that seems a bit too hard-coded. I was just wondering if there is a better way.

Comment: Since it's CSV, it _is string_ in nature.  How would you look at that and know what is a proper type for each value?  You presume a schema...where is it?  Other than pre-defined knowledge of columns, as you suggest, I'm not sure what else there is.

Comment: Total shot in the dark:  if you can use XML instead of CSV, you could:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162770(v=vs.110).aspx.  Regardless, that's the sort of thing you seem to be hoping for with CSV.

Comment: Set up a mapping for each field, then have a preprocessing method run on each value based on its column before insertion to convert.

Comment: Load your file into a staging table.  Update was necessary.  Write to real table from the staging table.

Comment: You have essentially hard coded your table datatypes so why not hard code a method that does the conversion/casting to the correct types

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to do this? I'm trying to do the same thing. The table schema is known in advance, but I don't know how to set up the mappings for each `DataColumn` object.

Comment: I eventually did it the hardcoded way as is "if column header is ID then type is int"